# how to prevent select item in dropdowlist using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I want prevent user to select dropdown list items using javascript methods. Is there anyway use `OnMouseKeyDown` so I can stop there. I donot want use `Enable=false`.

Javascripts gurus, help me out.

Comment: perhaps you should consider a different control if you don't want your user to select something from a `select` element. otherwise can you provide more detail about your scenario?

Comment: I am trying disable ddl, But when I do that. Font is changing ( looks like blur). So That is the reason I want prevent user to select drop down on based on his previlages.

Comment: "I want prevent user to select drop down on based on his privileges" Why render it at all?

Comment: yeah, i'm gonna go with "pick a different control". the look of a `select` element creates a certain expectation for the user, which is different than you are trying to give them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to open the select box but not change the selection, you can do the following:

```
<select onchange="this[0].selected = true">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Where you change the selected index to the item you wish to keep selected. As a side note, this usually isn't a very good idea from a user interface perspective.

Answer (score 0):

```
onfocus="this.blur()"
```

add that to the element

Answer (score 0):

let's try this in c#

```
string hardcode = "1"; // set as appropriate
myDropDownList.Attributes["onchange"] = "this.selectedIndex = " + hardcode + ";";
```

keep in mind if your user has javascript disabled this isn't going to work, and you should be doing verification on the server no matter what.

Comment: That's really bad from a usability perspective. You select item 4, it selects item 1. Not nice! :)

Comment: selected item will be there already. Just user has see the data (not to select).

Comment: @Marko of course it is, but this is the least painful way I can think of to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option>Select an option</option>
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#dropdown").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
        return false;
    });
});
```